# Low Search: Redirect if single result

Tags: ee2, low-search

I am trying to do the following - essentially redirect to the correct page if search query only returns a single result.

{if total_results == "1"}{redirect="{comment_url_title_auto_path}"}{/if}

This is working, however, it's also appending the domain to the URL, so the resulting redirect is

http://domain.com/http://domain.com/template/view/url-title/

Is this possible at all?

Regards,

Christiaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach should work just fine.

The `{comment_url_title_auto_path}` variable is parsed by native EE code. So if that results in an unexpected url, you might want to check the value of that setting in the [Channel Preferences](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#comment-page-url).

Comment: Thanks - that was it - the Channel preferences had the full domain in the URL path fields.